# Do I need specific configuration for Spatialite with GeoDjango?

Tags: django, geodjango, spatial-query, spatialite

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/, Spatialite supports `GeoQuerySet.distance()`. However, having imported an area list (`MultiPolygon` as `mpoly` attribute), I'm trying to do the following:

```
Area.objects.all().distance(center)
```

And instead of something usable, I only get an error message: "**ValueError: SQLite does not support linear distance calculations on geodetic coordinate systems.**"

What's wrong here, do I need some special configuration on Spatialite or is the documentation plain wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do anything regarding spatialite, but rather change the coordinate system (srid) you're using. Spatialite does distance calculations only on geographic coordinate systems, not geodetic. Check the SRID do you have in your model definition. Alternatively you can also switch to the postgis backend.

Comment: Excellent, I've set my Geometry field to 900913 and at least something worked. Have to figure out which projection I really need, but that's a great start. Thanks!

Comment: How to do that in a PointField() ??